# .Net Web Application Restrict access

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In a .Net what are the possible ways to restrict access of certain set of users gaining access to a web application. User Authentication is already there, but as the app is exclusive i wouldn't want it to get loaded.

My issues is the broadband connection the customer has provides dynamic ip, so cant restrict by ip. I would love to manage by MAC, but is there is any reliable way to find MAC?

Or if there is any other bright idea which i am missing out totally!

Comment: possible duplicate? stackoverflow.com/questions/3454858/how-to-get-client-mac-address-by-a-access-on-a-website

Comment: MAC is never exposed outside the local network and additionally, is very easy to spoof - most intel network cards allow it to be set using only stock drivers.

Comment: Its not almost duplicate Mads! In my case I would need the app although available on internet... but that should be a private internet... as in the app should only be accessible from only the allowed domains. My question is... Can that be done or not?

Comment: Basic i agree MAC wont be available outside the LAN... My query is how to limit the app access to only selected users... What can be the possible authentic parameters i can use to identify the request and thus allow or disallow the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of the build in authentication modules that run in the http pipeline (in front of your application). (Client certificate authentication, Windows, Basic, etc)

Comment: If you for example use client certificate authentication it will do authentication at network protocol level. A module in IIS will take care of this and only if the authentication succeeds your application will go runtime.

Comment: You talking about SSL certificate? If yes, then suggest something else... am holding on to it for now.

Comment: Yes, but it was just a example. There are also other builtin authentication modules that will allow you to login with username/password and runs in front of your application in the http pipeline.

Comment: Am kind of getting your point, however my need is to move beyond username/password which a user would already know and thus can access the app out of premise. My need is to limit the App accessibility to the physical premise.

So if the "physical premise" systems (desktop/laptop/palmtop/other devices) can register themselves only for accessing the app it'll be great.

Comment: Thanks Kees for the suggestion, i guess it would work. Will update you about it.